# infinite wedge product

Tags: geometry, banach-spaces

In the theory of manifolds, we use wedges to help define integration and after some work we prove Stoke's theorem. I'm wondering if we can make sense of integration for a Banach manifold (locally each point looks like a Banach space), assuming the dimension is countably infinite, does integration make sense? How do we define the wedge product?  Do we still get Stoke's theorem and other nice results?